# Restore LogicalVolumes LVM

Tags: linux, centos, lvm

Hi again I need some help I try to change the HDD from a centOS server an for reasons of connectivity I chose do it whit lvm commands and do something bad well i don't think was going to be that bad well the mater is I start whit

create the partition whit fdisk in a new dos table and create the pv whit `pvcreate /dev/sdb2`

After that I extend the vg whit

```
vgextend mycentosvg /dev/sdb2
```

Everything goes good until there i did pvmove like

```
pvmove -vb /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb2
```

And whit

```
lvs -a -o+devices
```

Was monitoring the process but i miss safely delete the pv from /dev/sda2 and reboot to restore the grub and there i should put the other disk and doit rigth but not I didn't  i just force the `pvreduce --reducemissing mycentosvg`

Then everything start to fail i try to mount the lv unsuccessful the reboot just whit the other disk and ask for the other disk hdd i did the same "oh my good" why i dont know but I did and know neither one have the lv "oh my good" my job depend on this what i shoul do i have not do anything else ! I need to restore it please !

```
[root@localhost ~]# pvs                                
  PV         VG Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree   
  /dev/sda2  cl lvm2 a--  <297.09g <297.09g
  /dev/sdb2     lvm2 ---   930.46g  930.46g

[root@localhost ~]# vgs
  VG #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize    VFree   
  cl   1   0   0 wz--n- <297.09g <297.09g

[root@localhost ~]# lvs
```

lvs dont give anything then i cant mount nothing

Comment: Try remove ada and boot from a bootable disk. Then see if you can mount the lvm's. If not, please advise output of pvs;vgs;lvs

Comment: davidgo i add the output's from those commands in this time i have both hdd connected and boot from a centos live dvd

Comment: What does the output of "lvscan -va" say/do for you?

Comment: Still nothing there, not output !

Comment: DO YOUR RESEARCH BEFORE TRYING THIS - IT COULD MAKE THINGS WORSE, AND I'VE NEVER HAD TO DO IT - vgck would appear to be analogous to an fsck for volume groups.  Not sure if running a vgcfgbackup would buy you any protection if it makes things worse.  Also, before you try this, do you have any backups in /etc/lvm/archive?  (See ttps://www.thegeekdiary.com/corruption-or-accidental-deletion-in-lvm-how-to-rebuild-lvm-from-archive-metadata-backups-in-rhel-centos/)

Comment: I have not bakups :( i have being reading about it is not cool there it's not an other way to restored like testdisk thankyou davidgo

Comment: I don't understand what you have written. Photorec may allow limited recovery of some files - although it sucks.

Comment: I did not do nothing else only what I write here, i get to this link http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/appnote/19386.html and it is very full of scenarios like my and did the next witout success

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111080/discussion-between-denn0n-and-davidgo).